# highchart desing issue regarding linerange on the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have a highchart which display some data onn the chart based on json date . But of the activity displalys on the wrong field even if it has starttime and end time  it is called

`copy_historic_db-prod` . Time duration between `sttime and edtime`is about  `1 hour` but it appears on the very far right of the chart.

[Here is the JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/6/)

Should I play with timeinverval to resolve this issue ?

or Any other suggestion .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly from your data:

```
}, {
    "name": "copy_historic_db -prod",
    "st_time_am_pm": " pm",
    "ed_time_am_pm": " pm",
    "intervals": [{
        "from": 1399723324000,
        "to": 1399727196000,
        "label": "completed",
        "color": "#000000"
    }]
}
```

Let's try it:

```
new Date(1399723324000); //returns Sat May 10 2014 14:02:04 GMT+0200 (CEST)
new Date(1399727196000); //returns Sat May 10 2014 15:06:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

Now, let's compare with some other (randomly chosen) point:

```
{
    "name": "avgpri -F",
    "st_time_am_pm": " pm",
    "ed_time_am_pm": " pm",
    "intervals": [{
        "from": 1399650494000,
        "to": 1399650859000,
        "label": "completed",
        "color": "#000000"
    }]
}
```

And:

```
new Date(1399650494000); //returns Fri May 09 2014 17:48:14 GMT+0200 (CEST)
new Date(1399650859000); //returns Fri May 09 2014 17:54:19 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

So as you can see, just your data for that point is the culprit: May 09 vs May 10.

See just disabled tooltip date format: http://jsfiddle.net/gtkd9096/7/

Comment: Yes. it looks like the problem ,.Thanks

Comment: How did you display "May" on xAxsis ?